# Would like to use (kanban) board in Azure Devops with Task cards on the board

Tags: azure-devops, task, kanban, sprint

In Azure devops it seems that you are only allowed to use userstories, issues, bugs as cards at the **Boards** in the menu. Our team would like to use tasks cards instead of a tasks checklist inside a userstory at boards. We would like to see that also a task is also added to the WIP limit if the task hit a column.

In sprints you are able to use tasks as cards but at boards not for which I am also curious to know why Microsoft has chosen this. Why in sprints it is allowed and at Kanban boards not?

If anybody has any good idea's or suggestions to work around this please let me know.

We could also use Userstory more as tasks but that is bit contradicting with the way we are using userstories

Answer (score 3):

Cause as you have mentioned, there is another sprint task board.

There are two types of boards available to you in Azure DevOps. Unable to use task in Kanban board is how it supposed to be. They are designed and used for different things.

- **Kanban boards** track requirements, are sprint-independent, and you
  monitor the flow through the cumulative flow chart.
- **Task boards** track tasks defined for a sprint and you monitor the flow
  via the sprint burndown chart.

**Each sprint is associated with a Taskboard that supports tracking tasks defined for the sprint.** You can monitor progress through capacity charts and the sprint burndown chart.

For an overview of the features supported on each backlog and board, see [Backlogs, boards, and plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-boards-plans?view=azure-devops).

For details about working in each type of board, see [Kanban basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-basics?view=azure-devops) and [taskboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/task-board?view=azure-devops).